# Should I close connection when using SessionFactoryUtils

Tags: java, hibernate, spring, orm

If I want to use SessionFactoryUtils to get Connection directly to execute some SQL statement, and join the same transaction.
Like this:

```
SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(getSessionFactory()).getConnection();
//some logic after Connection retrieved
```

Do I have to close Connection by myself? or just let it be and Hibernate Session will handle it for me?

Answer (score 3):

> If I want to use `SessionFactoryUtils` to get Connection directly to execute some SQL statement, and join the same transaction. (...) Do I have to close `Connection` by myself? or just let it be and Hibernate `Session` will handle it for me?

You are directly borrowing a connection from the pool here and there is no guarantee that a `Session` would get the same IMO. You are thus responsible for closing that connection properly and I'd suggest to use:

```
SessionFactoryUtils.getDataSource(getSessionFactory()).closeConnection(conn);
```

If you want to work with the connection managed by a `Session`, use `Session#doWork(Work)` (this new API replaces the old `Session#connection()` method which is deprecated and will be removed from Hibernate 4.x). In that case, the connection will be closed with the `Session`.

Or maybe just use [`Session#createSQLQuery(String)`](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29) as already suggested.

Actually, providing more context information (are you in a template, do you already have a Session, will you get one, etc) would really help to find the best solution (it might not be the chosen one).

#### See also

- Colin's answer in the Thread: [When using JdbcTemplate, how do I access the connection?](http://forum.springsource.org/showthread.php?t=9704#post695)

Answer (score 0):

I think all you need to do is to handle your session properly (i.e. flush it, close it, whatever is valid for your setup).

But why not to use [createSQLQuesry](http://ajava.org/online/hibernate3api/org/hibernate/Session.html#createSQLQuery%28java.lang.String%29) method of Session instead of getting direct connection?